# Calculating a smooth velocity of interaction touches

Tags: physics, multitouch

I have a touch game and it would be beneficial to be able to know the "velocity" of each touch on the screen.  Let me explain.

Right now I am already subtracting current touch position from previous ones to get a dt, however this is not working well. Sometimes the dt will show up as 0 even though the finger is moving.

What would be a good way to measure a smooth velocity of each touch considering that it can release, or touch back down at any moment?

I already have  method to track the position of each finger, I just need a way to get a smooth velocity.